Is it possible to open in app browser in the background in Flutter?
I am using flutter_web_auth_2 package to log in, which is fine, but logging out on Android is not working until clearing the cache and cookies from the last login.
I can clear them by opening the logout url in the in-app-browser, but then the in-app-browser stays up open. Is it possible to open in-app-browser without showing it to user? Or open and close it as soon as logout is successful?
